# Is it possible to have a RSS feed by using a Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, rss

Is it possible to have a RSS feed by using a Javascript code?

Comment: Are you talking about writing to one or reading one?

Comment: What is the question exactly? You want to parse/display a RSS feed using javascript? Or deliver your content using Javascript. The second is not possible completely using just javascript.

Comment: @Teja: Not possible with _clientside_ javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally possible.

If you want to use a local feed (on your own domain), you can simply use AJAX and parse that RSS feed.. This does not, however, work cross-site (as you might know), and unfortunately you cannot use this to get RSS feeds from other domains. (If you don't know AJAX, you can learn it at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) or [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/)).

But Google has a solution. Using the [Google AJAX Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/), you can read RSS feeds from other domains without AJAX. You can read [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) for it to get a basic understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

An RSS feed is a type of xml file at a url. I'm not sure how you'd accomplish that with javascript (unless it's server side javascript). I think you need to do some homework on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible. Create an Ajax request with JQuery.

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "[your xml rss url]",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(x) {
   $(x).find('foo').children().each(function(){

    if(this.nodeName == "bar")
    {
     var x = $(this).attr("bar1");
     var y = $(this).attr("bar2");
     var z = $(this).attr("bar3");
     return;

    }    

   });
```

[Jquery-Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

That depends what you mean. Probably not.

Comment: setting up a local news headlines rss feed that I can implement on a website. preferably something that can include associated images.  For example:  

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&tbs=nws%3A1&q=florida&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

I just wanted to make RSS feed a javascript framework..

Answer (score 0):

look at this jQuery plugin. It works great

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/